# Write some code that accepts an integer and prints the integers from 0 to that input integer in a spiral format

Tags: c#

Write some code that accepts an integer and prints the integers from 0 to that input integer in a spiral format.

For example, if I supplied 24 the output would be:

```
20 21 22 23 24
19  6  7  8  9
18  5  0  1 10
17  4  3  2 11
16 15 14 13 12
```

this is the code which i have tried but i am not able to get expected output as per the example please suggest for the same.

this is the actual output

```
25  24 23 22 21 
10   9  8  7 20 
11   2  1  6 19 
12   3  4  5 18 
13  14 15 16 17
```

---

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 5;
        printSpiral(n);
    }
    static void printSpiral(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                int x;
                x = Math.Min(Math.Min(i, j),
                    Math.Min(n - 1 - i, n - 1 - j));
                if (i <= j)

                    Console.Write((n - 2 * x) *
                                  (n - 2 * x) -
                                  (i - x) - (j - x) + "\t");
                else
                    Console.Write((n - 2 * x - 2) *
                                  (n - 2 * x - 2) +
                                  (i - x) + (j - x) + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is output you are getting from this logic?

Comment: please edit it into your question. It doesn't make much sense in a single line.

Comment: Take a look: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form/

Comment: @John i have shown the actual output and the expected one..please help me on this

Comment: @duDE already check with this code..but not getting expected output

Comment: you've written a spiral...just in the opposite direction to the "expected" version. I assume this is some kind of code challenge or homework? Is your version not acceptable? It meets the "spiral" definition. Or must it be **exactly** as per the other output in order to pass? The only other difference is you need to make sure you start at 0 instead of 1, but that should be be a small issue. Is that the point of your question? Or is it the direction which is the issue?

Comment: You'd need to debug why your 0 is being eaten

Comment: P.S. To make it start at 0 just add `- 1` to each of your calculations inside the Console.Write statements: `if (i <= j)

                    Console.Write((n - 2 * x) *
                                  (n - 2 * x) -
                                  (i - x) - (j - x) - 1  + "\t");
                else
                    Console.Write((n - 2 * x - 2) *
                                  (n - 2 * x - 2) +
                                  (i - x) + (j - x) - 1 + "\t");`

Comment: Does that solve your problem then? If so I will post it as the answer. You didn't answer my enquiries about the nature of your question.

Comment: @ADyson not exactly.... actually i want to input a number ..
For example, if I supplied 24 the output would be:
20 21 22 23 24
19 6 7 8 9
18 5 0 1 10
17 4 3 2 11
16 15 14 13 12

Comment: well it's trivial for you to use a search engine to find out how to accept input from the user. You can find out in a couple of seconds. Did you try?

Comment: @ADyson yes already try to do..
actually right now we declare the n=5..so it will be print the 
25  24 23 22 21 
10  9  8  7  20 
11  2  1  6  19 
12  3  4  5  18 
13  14 15 16 17
but when we put the n=24 or any thing else then it will be not as expected